# Bootcamp partiton in VirtualBox returns errors VERR_ACCESS_DENIED and VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR

Tags: macos, mac, windows, virtualbox

I have been using this guide: http://danielphil.github.io/windows/virtualbox/osx/2015/08/25/virtualbox-boot-camp.html

But when I try and mount the .vmdk I get this error:

> Permission problem accessing the file for the medium
>   '/Users/jordan/win10raw.vmdk' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).
>
> Result Code:  VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004) Component:  MediumWrap
>   Interface:  IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda} Callee: 
>   IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} Callee RC: 
>   VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)

I have tried this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html

with no luck mounting it on the ide controller

Comment: Update: in disk util on the info panel it shows writable as false.

Comment: MacOSX can't write to the NTFS volume that Bootcamp uses but with special software such as NTFSforMac you can

Comment: When you say the error occurred when you tried to *mount*. Did you really mean when you tried to *open*?

Comment: When I tried to add it to the ide controller is when it happened sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Just so you know, you have to insert a @David somewhere in your comment or I will not be notified. Next time when posting a comment, click on help for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out you have to run this command in Terminal: 
`sudo chown (username) win10*.vmdk`